# Crop Landsat image using Extent in R

Tags: raster, r, extents

I'm following a tutorial on Remote Sensing within R and I'm attempting to crop a Landsat image, however I'm getting the error: 
    Error in validityMethod(object) : invalid extent: ymin >= ymax

My code is:

```
# Find the current extent
extent(landsat)
class       : Extent 
xmin        : 269625 
xmax        : 337155 
ymin        : 3221685 
ymax        : 3289215 

# Create new extent object
e <- extent(250000, 325000, -3150000,-3250000)

# Crop Landsat
l_crop <- crop(landsat, extent(e))
```

Is there an error in the syntax or have I missed something?

Comment: You've got *negative* Y coordinates (with minus signs) in your `extent`, but *positive*  coordinates in your `landsat` data. Is this simply a typo? Did you really mean `e <- extent(250000, 325000, 3150000, 3250000)`

Comment: The e object is already an extent class object and calling the extent function  will cause issues. You do not need to creat the object, just fixe the negative  values issue and call extent, with the desired coordinates, in the crop function.

Comment: Thanks, although I get this: `Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap` when I try `l_crop <- crop(landsat, extent(250000, 325000, -3250000, -3150000))`, I have removed the e object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not all that familiar with R but it looks like you've just mixed up your ymin and ymax values when you create your extent object:

```
# Arguments are xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax
# Note: ymin > ymax which is invalid.
e <- extent(250000, 325000, -3150000, -3250000)
```

If you change it to:

```
e <- extent(250000, 325000, -3250000, -3150000)
```

That should create a valid extent object.